# How to show the title bar in the design review?

Tags: android, listview

When I am designing a layout, the design review does not show the title bar, but the simulator can show the title bar, as you can see below:
[image]

My style.xml is showing as follows:
[image]

Also, my Manifest is writen as follows:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Is there any ways that I can keep the title bar all the time when I design my layout? even though I create many layout file, I still hope that every layout can keep the title bar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change theme in Editor

like below image it will work

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

Check the current Theme in the Android Studio Design Preview : 
[image]

It must not end with ".NoActionBar", you can set your theme "AppTheme".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 28 API. please change `API VERSION` to `26` and use this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```